# Expected exit time of Brownian motion from a rectangle

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $R=(a,b)\times(c,d)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $B_s$ be two dimensional Brownian motion with starting point $x \in R$. Is there an easy way to calculate $E_x(\tau_R)$ where $\tau_R$ is the exit time for $R$?

Comment: Easy? Doubt it. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.5142.pdf) (on p.~21/22) you find the formula for the expected value of the exit time from a square

Comment: It can be deduced from the distribution of exit time for a one-dimensional Browinan motion using the independence of components.

Comment: Thanks. I had the hope that there is some way which is as "easy" as the case in which the domain is a disc and where I don't need to know the whole distribution.